# In CouchDB how do you take in parameters from REST call

Tags: json, rest, couchdb

Hi so I'm new to CouchDB looks great so far, but really struggling with what **must be simple to do!**

I have documents structured as:

```
{
   "_id" : "245431e914ce42e6b2fc6e09cb00184d",
   "_rev": "3-2a69f0325962b93c149204aa3b1fa683",
   "type": "student",
   "studentID": "12345678",
   "Name": "Test",
   "group: "A"
}
```

And would like to access them them with queries such as `http://couchIP/student?group=A` or something like that. Are Views what I need here? I don't understand how to take the parameter from the query in the Map functions in Views. example:

```
function(doc,req) {
   if(req.group==='A'){
        emit(doc.id, doc.name);
   } 
}
```

Is my understanding of how Couch is working wrong or what's my problem here? Thanks  in advance, I'm sure this is Couch 101

Already read through http://guide.couchdb.org/ but it didn't really answer the question!

Comment: View functions are not and should not be depended from request state. You need to emit records by doc.group and query view with `key` query parameter. If you still think, that your view need to interact with user request than use the list functions.

Comment: Like I said I'm a beginner, basically I'm looking for a couch function where I can make http://query+params - somehow use those params to input or retrieve data, but I can find no way of retrieving those params or using them with in Couch if that makes sense. Will look into list functions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need views to achieve the desired results.

Define the following map function inside a view of a design document. ( let's name the view "byGroup" and assume this lives in a design document named "_design/students" )

```
function(doc) {
   if(doc.group){
    emit(doc.group,null);
   } 
}
```

Results can be obtained from the following url

```
http://couchIP:5984/dbname/_design/students/_view/byGroup?startkey="A"&endkey="A"&include_docs=true
```

To have friendly url couchdb also provides url rewriting options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to some further reading about views and the relevance that they return key/pair values.

It's not clear what you want to return from the view so I'll guess. If you want to return the whole document you'd create a view like:

```
function (doc) { emit(doc.group, doc) };
```

This will emit the group name as a key which you can lookup against, the whole doc will be returned as the value when you look it up.

If you want to just have access to the names of those users you want to do something like:

```
function (doc) { emit(doc.group, doc.name) };
```

Comment: My problem is not in what I want returned, but how to take in parameters from the query, or whether views are what I need to do this. Here is one of my stored views, `http://localhost:5984/spms/_design/test/_view/test` now how can I add a parameter to use e.g. `http://localhost:5984/spms/_design/test/_view/test?ID=xxx` - My main problem is I can't retrieve the value of the parameter in the map function.

Answer (score 1):

Your question arises from a misconception about what a `view` does. Views use `map/reduce` to generate a representation of your data. You have no control of the output of your view in your query because the view is updated according to changes in your DB documents only.

Using a `list` is also not a good option. It may seem that you can use knowledge of your request in your `list` to generate a different output depending on the query parameters but this is wrong because couchdb uses `ETags` for caching and this means that most times you will get the same answer regardless of your list parameters since the underlying documents won't have changed. There is a trick though to fool couchdb in this case and this implies using two different alternating users but I wouldn't even try this way because surely there are easier ways to achieve your objectives and you can probably solve your problem using `group` as a key in your map function.

Comment: Hi joscos, thanks for answer. ok now I'm very confused. I thought the REST API you would have the the full set of DB functions to work with, e.g. select all documents where group is A, B etc. I thought that would be base functionality, that you wouldn't need to fool or hack couchDB to that do, as that's pretty much what everyone would need from a DB!!?

Comment: Well, couchdb is a bit different. You don't have the option to run ad-hoc queries. This is a limitation but you can still do a lot of stuff if you use views and the query API. I recommend reading this to understand what you can do and how to do it: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html

Comment: Also, if you miss very much SQL but you still want some of the functionality you would get with couch, then mongodb is a good choice.